# Guaranteed Message delivery

Tags: c#, signalr, rabbitmq

I am looking at architecture design for real-time message between the applications (hosted (web) and installed windows clients). As the windows client are installed on customer premises we will not have control over the firewall i.e. opening any ports.

So I thought of using SignalR to send instance notification using http over websocket or fallback technology. Our windows client currently using .Net 4.0 Framework.

I did some research about guaranteed delivery of message over signalr and people suggested to acknowledge message with GUID but not sure how I can implement this idea. Also when client is not connected I need to queue the message on a RabbitMQ and onConnected just send all the messages from the queue.

```
namespace SignalRHub.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string who, string data)
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            List<string> groups = new List<string>();
            groups.Add(name);
            groups.Add(who);

            Message message = new Message()
            {
                messageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                data = data
            };

            Clients.Groups(groups).addNewMessageToPage(name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
        }

        public void AcknowledgeServer(Guid messageId)
        {
            // Process the message acknowledge
            var msgGuid = messageId;
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public Guid messageId { get; set; }
        public String data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I managed doing this in few steps.

1. persist messages in a repository with an Id
2. on the send /connect event, get all unprocessed messages and send them
3. on the client side, send an acknowledgement to the server and remove messages from the repository

By design, signalR cannot guarantee the client will receive the message *and* receive it only once, because even if you implement such a protocol, you can lose the ack message and still get the message twice.

First approach : the server send event trigger addNewMessages for all unprocessed messages. Could do the trick but what if the send event is never called...

```
//just a sample repo : should be persisted, thread safe ...
public static class MessageRepository
{
    public static List<Message> UnprocessedMessages = new List<Message>();

    public static void AddMessage(Message msg)
    {
        UnprocessedMessages.Add(msg);
    }

    public static List<Message> GetMessagesByIssuer(string issuer)
    {
        return UnprocessedMessages.Where(m => m.Issuer.Equals(issuer)).ToList();
    }

    public static void Remove(Guid id)
    {
        if (UnprocessedMessages.Any(m => m.messageId.Equals(id)))
        {
            var message = UnprocessedMessages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.messageId.Equals(id));
            UnprocessedMessages.Remove(message);
        }
    }
}


[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string who, string data)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        List<string> groups = new List<string>();
        groups.Add(name);
        groups.Add(who);

        Message message = new Message()
        {
            messageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            data = data,
            Issuer = name,
            Receiver = who,
            CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        MessageRepository.AddMessage(message);
        var unProcessedMessages = MessageRepository.GetMessagesByIssuer(name).OrderBy(m => m.CreationDate).ToList();

        unProcessedMessages.ForEach(m =>
        {
            Clients.Groups(groups).addNewMessageToPage(name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m));
        });


    }

    public void AcknowledgeServer(Guid messageId)
    {
        // Process the message acknowledge
        var msgGuid = messageId;
        MessageRepository.Remove(msgGuid);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public Guid messageId { get; set; }
    public String data { get; set; }
    public String Issuer { get; set; }
    public String Receiver { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a second approach (a better one in my opinion).  You have C# client singleton with a Timer which checks your repository periodically and, then send unprocessed messages. You should also remove expired messages.

```
public class PresenceMonitor
{
    private Timer _timer;

    // How often we plan to check if the connections in our store are valid
    private readonly TimeSpan _presenceCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


    public PresenceMonitor()
    {

    }

    public void StartMonitoring()
    {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(_ =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Check();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Don't throw on background threads, it'll kill the entire process
                    Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
                }
            },
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            _presenceCheckInterval);
        }
    }

    private void Check()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        var messages = MessageRepository.GetAllMessages();
        messages.ForEach(m =>
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                List<string> groups = new List<string>();
                groups.Add(m.Issuer);
                groups.Add(m.Receiver);

                context.Clients.Groups(groups).addNewMessageToPage(m.Issuer, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

And in your `startuc` class, init the `Monitor`.

Comment: when client A send message to client B, client A will invoke send method, so do I have to add message to repo and get all the message and send to client from the repo. if you have few minutes can you please update my code so i can understand it better and I am not worried about client receiving duplicate messages due to acknowledgement lost and it important they don't lose any messages.